# Help building an E-commerce site

Tags: e-commerce, web-traffic

Guys, I want to build an e-commerce site on asp.net.  My query is: when two users simultaneously buy something, how would the two records get inserted in my database?  Would there be a lock? Can anyone explain how this would be or can be handled.

Also, I want to handle peak traffic and also control the average data allotted to each user.  I am thinking of using a plug-in.  Any suggestions here?

Comment: I am detecting a potential problem here in that it seems like you are thinking of updating the quantity in stock of some item when an order is placed. That would be problematic for many reasons. To the OP: I think you are worrying about the wrong things right now.

Comment: you shuld use nolock keyword in sql query table in mssql it will control locking issues

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought but if your just starting a new online store its highly unlikely you'll run into any problems like this for some time?

Secondly, Databases take care of themselves and your web server does all the work of handling traffic and allocating resources. You shouldn't be doing this at a web code level.

Answer (score 0):

The RDBMS handles the locking for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better solution is a free ecommerce solution, as it'll have a lot of optimisation for large traffic already. Is there a specific reason not to use one of the many solutions already available?