# E commerce Design

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, e-commerce

We are designing an e-commerce web site using asp.net. We are using a basic design and don't know if we can add something or shift onto a better version of asp or silverlight etc. We would like your suggestions.

We are making 3 main pages one for the login, another for the products and one for the payment. Whenever there is a purchase we insert a record in our database. We have two tables, one for daily transactions and another for history. The records whose status (shipment done, order delivered) is updated can be seen on the customer's request through a view created on the history. Also we are planning to send an email to the customer once a transaction is done or the status is updated. (SQL provides the feature I guess sp_send_mail). Also I would like to handle peak traffic and control the average data per user.

We are planning to use compression on IIS to control data and have heard about using static pages to reduce data transfer. But I am not sure how it would work. We would like to hear any improvements, modifications and suggestions to the above.

Comment: Duplicate version without spelling problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120621/help-building-an-e-commerce-site

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your server version.
Anyway, IIS has its own compression features for dynamic and static content. It's native internal module and I guess it works very quickly.
If you need more flexible configuration, you can pay attention on [Helicon Ape](http://www.helicontech.com/ape). **mod_gzip** and **mod_cache** together can improve your performance. One important advantage is flexibility. You can set different compression level for different MIME types.
Simple example:

```
SetEnvIf mime text/html User-Agent (?!MSIE).* gzip=9
```

It enables Gzip compression with level 9 for HTML files and excludes Internet Explorer.